# How do I flag as "Should be a comment"

Tags: support, not-an-answer

I've just come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13060907/916299) which should be a comment on the question. When an answer like this is in the review queues, there is a "This should be a comment.." option, but this flag doesn't seem to be available for moderator attention.

What should I do in this case please? Just down vote and leave a comment?

---

*I've just noticed that this is also quite an old answer. Does this have any bearing on how to handle it?*

Comment: The age of a post is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Not an answer is appropriate.

Comment: @pantarei, I should just read. :P "It should possibly be an edit, **a comment**.."

Comment: Come to think of it, the question is probably off topic too! Borderline at best

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If an answer should have been a comment, and isn't actually attempting to answer the question, then it's Not An Answer.