# How literally should I interpret "It should possibly be a comment" flag?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, late-answers

So I recently unlocked the review queue and I decided to try it out and see how it works.

During the reviewing process I ran into two "Late Answers" to two separate questions, where in both cases I had a very similar problem with the answer:

#### 1) [How do I create a multiline TextField in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471973/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-textfield-in-swiftui/65570559#65570559)

The top accepted answer is quite in-depth, even has an update to it to keep the answer up to date, has a solid explanation and a lengthy code example showing how the solution should be implemented.

The [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65570559/5843769) however, says something along the lines of "You can just use X instead..." which is like a 10 word sentence without an explanation, examples or reasoning behind that.

#### 2) [Fastlane screengrab on Android 30 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278826/fastlane-screengrab-on-android-30-emulator/65569747#65569747)

This question doesn't have an answer to it, but the [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65569747/5843769) fits the previous description again. We're talking about a 10 word sentence along the lines of "Just use a different version instead...".

---

What do I do?

Well I could first of all downvote the answer for it being very low quality, but quick research says that [downvoting pushes out off the front page but doesn't remove it. This means that it is somewhat less likely to be seen by other active members who could flag it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193916/why-shouldnt-i-downvote-spam-that-ive-already-flagged/193917). Obviously this isn't "obvious spam" but I believe the answer should be flagged and so I want the answer to get more attention!

So the other option that I have is to simply flag it. Clicking on the flag shows me the menu with "not an answer" having "it should possibly be a comment" in its description. With the little experience that I have, I am still quite certain that one sentence, one line answers should definitely be comments and [thus should be flagged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302518/how-do-i-flag-as-should-be-a-comment). I obviously hit the flag for "not an answer" for both answers I'm reviewing.

---

Fast forward to today, I see both of those flags got declined with a note that flags should not be used to indicate wrong answers! While reviewing the answers once again I even noticed that two other different users probably had a similar idea leaving a comment saying "This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker." At this point I'm pretty much staring at my screen thinking "I KNOW RIGHT, THIS SHOULD BE A COMMENT?", but the "this should be a comment" flag is apparently the wrong approach...

What's the ***right*** approach here? Am I interpreting the flag too literally?

Comment: It's a poor answer, but the information contained in it *could* arguably solve the problem, so it's not VLQ/NAA. I believe it *is* flaggable for deletion because multiple other answers have said the same thing already (and in more detail). See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266469. Raise a custom flag for this. If the info in the answer *wasn't* repeating what others had already said: (1) Downvote (2) If you think the answer helps no one, and you're 20k+, vote to delete

Comment: Note that the linked question on downvoting is about *questions*, so it isn't relevant here (plus bad answers aren't critical to remove quickly like spam anyway). Never be afraid to downvote low-quality answers, whether or not they're flag-worthy.

Comment: Note that a one-liner in an Answer doesn't make it a poor Answer. Lots of very good Answers are just one line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've identified two pretty low-quality answers. If I were you, I would downvote these. As stated in the tooltip, a downvote on an answer means, "this answer is not useful".

However, both *are* attempting to provide an answer to the question that was asked, so there is no cause for a moderator to delete them.

You seem to be operating under the misbelief that comments are for short, "mini"-answers. That is not the case. [Comments are for suggesting clarifications/improvements to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Neither of these answers were suggesting either a clarification or improvement. Both were attempting to answer the question that was asked. That makes your "not an answer" flag invalid.

A moderator charitably assumed that you were flagging the answers because they were incorrect, which is why they chose to decline your flag with the reason that "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". Perhaps a better decline reason would have been, "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it" (since there was no reason to believe that those were not valid attempts to answer the question that was asked).

> I could first of all downvote the answer for it being very low quality, but quick research says that [downvoting pushes out off the front page but doesn't remove it. This means that it is somewhat less likely to be seen by other active members who could flag it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193916/why-shouldnt-i-downvote-spam-that-ive-already-flagged/193917). Obviously this isn't "obvious spam" but I believe the answer should be flagged and so I want the answer to get more attention!

Yes, downvoting is what you should do for low-quality answers. What you've linked to is a Q&A discussing whether *spam* should be downvoted. There is no reason to downvote spam: you should just flag it as spam. But neither of the answers you reviewed were spam, so the advice given in the linked Q&A does not apply. These are not even non-obvious spam. They are in no way [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

There is no reason whatsoever to flag these posts. The "not an answer" and "very low quality" flags mean, "this needs to be immediately deleted by a moderator". There is no cause for a moderator to delete either of those two posts, as they were valid attempts to answer the question.

> So the other option that I have is to simply flag it. Clicking on the flag shows me the menu with "not an answer" having "it should possibly be a comment" in its description. With the little experience that I have, I am still quite certain that one sentence, one line answers should definitely be comments and [thus should be flagged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302518/how-do-i-flag-as-should-be-a-comment). I obviously hit the flag for "not an answer" for both answers I'm reviewing.

A theme is emerging: it seems that you are searching for advice, but not actually *reading* the advice that you are finding. Servy's answer is only one sentence long and pretty clear. It says:

> If an answer should have been a comment, and isn't actually attempting to answer the question, then it's Not An Answer.

Since both of those were attempting to answer the question, they don't meet the guidelines established for the "not an answer" flag.

As I mentioned above, you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about the purpose of comments. Comments are not meant as a place for low-quality answers to be posted.

Note that there is no "it should possibly be a comment" flag. That's just part of the description for the "not an answer" flag. It isn't the only thing found in the description. You need to read the whole description. **You should interpret the flag description *very* literally—literally to mean "this is not an attempt to answer the question".**

### Related reading:

- [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)
- [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)
- [Is "very short answer" an answer or comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350305/is-very-short-answer-an-answer-or-comment)
- [Are super short answers really Not an Answer (NAA)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362328/are-super-short-answers-really-not-an-answer-naa)
- [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505)